# Инициализация битовой маски

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

Изучаю битовые операции и столкнулся со следующей задачей: Дано целое число(int) и n-й разряд. Необходимо инициализировать переменную-маску с 1 в старшем и n-м бите и применить ее к заданному числу.
Как установить 1 в n-м бите я разобрался: `x = x | (1<<n)`, а вот как быть со старшем битом не совсем понимаю в силу недостатка знаний.
Собственно мой вопрос заключается в том, как инициализировать переменную-маску с 1 в старшем бите.

Comment: `целое число(int)` — очень интересно, что имеется в виду под старшим битом знакового целого числа. Бит знака? С `unsigned int` все просто...

Comment: @Harry в задании написано: Маска должна быть инициализирована единицей в старшем разряде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В старшем бите:

```
unsigned int mask = 1u << (sizeof(unsigned int)*8-1);
```

В старшем бите и n-м:

```
unsigned int mask = 1u << (sizeof(unsigned int)*8-1);
mask |= 1u << n;
```

Comment: а понятно! спасибо огромное!

Comment: Спасибо здесь принимает форму принятого ответа (птичка слева).